# how do i have a link to a page and ajax link in gridview yii

Tags: yii

When user clicks on the main message, the message is read and is redirected to the messages.

```
'value'=>function($data,$row){
   $id =Yii::app()->user->getId();
   if ($data->id) ==Yii::app()->user->getId()) 
   return CHtml::link(substr($data->comments, 0, 70)."...", 
           Yii::app()-createUrl("controller/comments", array("id"=>$data->message_id)), 
           array("controller/ajaxRead", "id"=>$data->id),array("class"=>"ajaxRead"));
   else...blah
```

What I have here is the message inbox.. the link goes to the messages, to "controller/comments". So I want to show the link but it's the first message of it. When user clicks, "controller/ajaxRead" is called.

shows the initial message

```
substr($data->comments, 0, 70)
```

the link it goes to when the user clicks

```
Yii::app()-createUrl("controller/comments", array("id"=>$data->message_id))
```

and the ajax link, when clicked changes to read

```
array("controller/ajaxRead", "id"=>$data->id),array("class"=>"ajaxRead"));
```

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: do you want to show a link?

Comment: your question is not clear please add some more details like what you want to do.

Comment: okay i updated.. hopefully it's more clear